# Refactoring to Partial Classes - Guidance

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring, naming-conventions, partial-classes

I am dealing with a huge codebehind of a an ASP.NET user control. I am taking the approach of refactoring the huge class into a number of partial clasees separted by UI intent.

Is there guidance on:

- Number of partial classes I am must constrain myself to.
- Naming or names to be given toof the partial class files.

Answer (score 3):

1. There's no limit to the number of Partial Class files you can use. They all compile into a single class at compile time. The more partial class files, though, the more confusing things could be when trying to find different functionality in the class.
2. I would name the files starting with the class name and then follow up with which concern the file was addressing. That way you're a little more clear about what is in each file.

You should also be careful about your class. If a single class is addressing several different UI Concerns to the point that you feel it should be separated into separate files it sounds like your class should be broken up into several smaller, more concise classes (rather than a single monolithic class defined across several files).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a partial classes limitation.

About file naming, again - no limitation. It could be anything.

My personal preference would be [MainClassName].[aspect].cs,

for example: *MyHugeControl.Reports.cs*, *MyHugeControl.Data.cs*, etc.